# How to enumerate all Bluetooth services?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, bluetooth

I want to get the list of available Bluetooth services for any Bluetooth device.

I found [BluetoothEnumerateInstalledServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothenumerateinstalledservices) from Windows API, but it enumerates only Installed services. This way I get a list of 3 services instead of 4.

How do I get a list of all services on a Bluetooth device?

[image]

Comment: Why the `c#` and `c++` tags?  Is your intent to use c++/CLI?

Comment: @MickyD Because it does not matter c# or c++. I will call c++ code from c#. Any answer from c# or c++ solution will be valid.

Answer (score 0):

I found an one way, but it does not provide full necessary information:

```
    #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <Ws2bth.h>
    #pragma comment(lib, "Bthprops.lib")
    #include <BluetoothAPIs.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        WSADATA data;
        if (WSAStartup(0x0202, &data) != 0)
        {
            // Выход по ошибке
            printf("WSACleanup() failed with error code %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
        #define BUF_SIZE 10240    
        WSAQUERYSET* pQuerySet = (WSAQUERYSET*) new BYTE[BUF_SIZE];
        ZeroMemory(pQuerySet, BUF_SIZE);
        pQuerySet->dwSize = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
        pQuerySet->dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;

        // Запускаем поиск устройств
        HANDLE lookupHandle = 0;
        int    lookupResult = WSALookupServiceBegin(pQuerySet,
            LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_FLUSHCACHE |
            LUP_RETURN_TYPE | LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_RES_SERVICE,
            &lookupHandle);
        if (lookupResult != 0)
        {
            // Ошибка при инициализации поиска
            printf("WSALookupServiceBegin() failed with error code %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            printf("WSALookupServiceBegin() is OK\n");       
        }

        while (lookupResult == 0)
        {
            DWORD  bufferLen = BUF_SIZE;

            lookupResult = WSALookupServiceNext(lookupHandle,
                LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_RETURN_ADDR,
                &bufferLen,
                pQuerySet);
            if (lookupResult != 0)
                break;
    
            DWORD addressLength = 128;
            char* addressString = new char[addressLength];

            int result = WSAAddressToString(pQuerySet->lpcsaBuffer->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr,
                pQuerySet->lpcsaBuffer->RemoteAddr.iSockaddrLength,
                NULL,
                (LPWSTR)addressString,
                &addressLength);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                printf("\n          WSAAddressToString() for remote address failed with error code %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            }
            else {
                printf("MAC: ");
                printf("%S ", addressString);
                printf("Name: ");
                wprintf(pQuerySet->lpszServiceInstanceName);
                printf("\n");        

                WSAQUERYSET* pQuerySetServices = (WSAQUERYSET*) new BYTE[BUF_SIZE];
                ZeroMemory(pQuerySetServices, BUF_SIZE);
                pQuerySetServices->dwSize = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
                pQuerySetServices->dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
                pQuerySetServices->dwNumberOfCsAddrs = 0;
                pQuerySetServices->lpszContext = (LPWSTR)addressString;
                pQuerySetServices->lpServiceClassId = (GUID*)&L2CAP_PROTOCOL_UUID;

                HANDLE lookupServicesHandle = 0;
                int lookupServicesResult = WSALookupServiceBegin(pQuerySetServices, LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_RETURN_TYPE | LUP_RES_SERVICE | LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_RETURN_COMMENT, &lookupServicesHandle);
                if (lookupServicesResult != 0)
                {
                    printf("WSALookupServiceBegin() failed with error code %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                }
                else
                {
                    while (lookupServicesResult == 0)
                    {
                        DWORD  bufferLen = BUF_SIZE;

                        lookupServicesResult = WSALookupServiceNext(lookupServicesHandle,
                            LUP_RETURN_ALL,
                            &bufferLen,
                            pQuerySetServices);
                        if (lookupServicesResult != 0)
                            break;

                        GUID guid = *pQuerySetServices->lpServiceClassId;
                        OLECHAR* guidString;
                        StringFromCLSID(guid, &guidString);

                        printf("    ");
                        wprintf(guidString);
                        printf(" ");
                        wprintf(pQuerySetServices->lpszServiceInstanceName);
                        printf("\n");
                    }
                    WSALookupServiceEnd(lookupServicesHandle);
                }
            }
        }

        WSALookupServiceEnd(lookupHandle);
        WSACleanup();
    }
```

Output:

```
    MAC: (00:1E:B5:8C:64:49) Name: Moga Pro HID
        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Android Controller Gen-2(ACC)
    MAC: (30:39:26:FE:C8:62) Name: SBH20
        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Hands-Free unit
        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Headset
        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

This method can get a right count of services, but the GUIDs always empty and some services does not have readable name.